# Generate multiple Invoice in One document using itextsharp

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, itext

I want to generate multiple invoice as well as single invoice using given code. When user pass value in this function `GenInvoice(int clientId, string InvoiceNum, bool SinglePage)`  `SinglePage= true` then the code will print multiple invoice in same document after page break .

**Problem**
When i send multiple invoice number in my function this function generate and singlepage to true then after that this function not generate multiple pdf in same document.  i am passing the value to the function 
`GenInvoice(1362, "85561,85231",true);`

**My code is below**

```
public void GenInvoice(int clientId, string InvoiceNum, bool SinglePage)
    {


        string[] arg = InvoiceNum.Split(',');
        InOnePdf = SinglePage;
        InvNumber = InvoiceNum;
        if (arg.Length != 0)
        {

            foreach (string s in arg)
            {
                TotalCount = i + 1;
                if (TotalCount == 1)
                {
                    doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 50, 50);
                    fs = null;
                    table = new PdfPTable(8);
                    //string pdfFilePath = "";
                }

                try
                {
                    SqlConnection connWin = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString());
                    if (connWin.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connWin.Open();
                    }

                    string Command = "SELECT COMPANY,ADDRLN1,ADDRLN2,ADDRLN3 FROM config";
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command, connWin);
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    /* Getting Client Information*/

                    string ClientCommand = "SELECT BCLIENT,BCITY,BADDR, BSTPROV + '' +  BZIPPOSTAL AS BSTZIP , 'Attn: ' + CONTACT AS Contact  From client WHERE CLIENTID = " + clientId;

                    SqlDataAdapter dataClientInfo = new SqlDataAdapter(ClientCommand, connWin);
                    DataSet _dstClientInfo = new DataSet();
                    dataClientInfo.Fill(_dstClientInfo);

                    /* END client Information */

                    string InvoiceTotal = "SELECT O.INVNUM,C.CLIENTNUM , CONVERT(varchar(10), O.INVDATE,101)AS INVDATE  ,O.TOTAL  from orde_ O INNER JOIN client C ON C.CLIENTID = O.CLIENTID" +
                                            " INNER JOIN Billing B ON B.INVNUM = O.INVNUM " +
                                             "WHERE O.CLIENTID =" + clientId + "AND O.INVNUM  IN  (" + "'" + InvNumber + "')";
                    //IN''85561','87918''
                    SqlDataAdapter dataInvTotal = new SqlDataAdapter(InvoiceTotal, connWin);

                    DataSet _dstInvTotal = new DataSet();
                    dataInvTotal.Fill(_dstInvTotal);

                    string InvDesc = "SELECT O.ORDERNUM,O.TOTAL,Se.DES_,CONVERT(varchar(10),O.ORDDATE,101)AS ORDDATE, DROPOFF from orde_ O INNER JOIN SERVICE Se ON Se.SERVICEID = O.SERVICEID " +
                                       " WHERE O.CLIENTID =" + clientId + " AND O.INVNUM  IN  (" + "'" + InvNumber + "')";

                    SqlDataAdapter dataInvDesc = new SqlDataAdapter(InvDesc, connWin);

                    DataSet dsDetail = new DataSet();
                    dataInvDesc.Fill(dsDetail);




                    #region variabl
                    string _ClientNum = "";
                    string _invdate = "";
                    decimal _total = 0;
                    string _invNum = "";

                    foreach (DataTable tabledata in _dstInvTotal.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in tabledata.Rows)
                        {
                            decimal _totalL = 0;
                            Decimal.TryParse(dr["TOTAL"].ToString(), out _totalL);
                            _total = _total + _totalL;
                            _invdate = dr["INVDATE"].ToString();
                            _ClientNum = dr["CLIENTNUM"].ToString();
                            _invNum = dr["INVNUM"].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion




                    string ApplicationDirectroy = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FolderPath"].ToString();
                    string appDirectory = ApplicationDirectroy;
                    //appDirectory = appDirectory + @"\Temp";
                    if (ApplicationDirectroy != string.Empty)
                    {

                        if (!Directory.Exists(ApplicationDirectroy))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(ApplicationDirectroy);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please specify the Folder Path And Folder Name Where PDF Generate  ");
                        return;

                    }

                    Random rr = new Random();
                    string filename = rr.Next(1111, 9999).ToString();
                    pdfFilePath = appDirectory + @"\" + filename + ".pdf";
                    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create));
                    doc.Open();

                    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {


                        PdfPCell _CompanyName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["COMPANY"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE, 12)));
                        _CompanyName.Colspan = 4;
                        _CompanyName.Border = 0;

                        table.AddCell(_CompanyName);


                        PdfPCell InvoiceHeader = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("INVOICE  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 16)));
                        InvoiceHeader.Colspan = 4;
                        InvoiceHeader.Border = 0;
                        table.AddCell(InvoiceHeader);

                        PdfPTable pob = new PdfPTable(1);

                        PdfPCell pob1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ADDRLN1"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                        pob1.Colspan = 1;
                        pob1.Border = 0;
                        pob.AddCell(pob1);

                        PdfPCell pob2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ADDRLN2"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                        pob2.Colspan = 1;
                        pob2.Border = 0;
                        pob.AddCell(pob2);
                        PdfPCell pob3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ADDRLN3"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                        pob3.Colspan = 1;
                        pob3.Border = 0;
                        pob.AddCell(pob3);

                        PdfPCell pob4 = new PdfPCell(pob);
                        pob4.Colspan = 4;
                        pob4.Border = 0;
                        table.AddCell(pob4);
                    }




                    PdfPTable right = new PdfPTable(5);

                    PdfPCell right1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice Number  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    right1.Colspan = 3;
                    right1.Border = 0;
                    right1.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    right1.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    right1.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    right1.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    //right1.BackgroundColor
                    right.AddCell(right1);

                    PdfPCell right2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Page  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    right2.Colspan = 2;
                    right2.Border = 1;
                    right2.Border = 0;
                    right2.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    right2.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    right2.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    right2.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(right2);

                    PdfPCell rightL1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_invNum, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    rightL1.Colspan = 3;
                    rightL1.Border = 1;
                    rightL1.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL1.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL1.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL1.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL1);

                    PdfPCell rightL2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" 1  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL2.Colspan = 2;
                    rightL2.Border = 1;
                    rightL2.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    rightL2.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL2.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL2.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL2);

                    PdfPCell rightL3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CLIENT NUMBER  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL3.Colspan = 3;
                    rightL3.Border = 0;
                    rightL3.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL3.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL3.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL3.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL3);

                    PdfPCell rightL4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TERMS  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL4.Colspan = 2;
                    rightL4.Border = 0;
                    rightL4.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    rightL4.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL4.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL4.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL4);

                    PdfPCell rightL5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_ClientNum, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    rightL5.Colspan = 3;
                    rightL5.Border = 0;
                    rightL5.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL5.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL5.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL5.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    right.AddCell(rightL5);

                    PdfPCell rightL6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NO RECEIPT  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL6.Colspan = 2;
                    rightL6.Border = 0;
                    rightL6.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    rightL6.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL6.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL6.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    right.AddCell(rightL6);

                    PdfPCell rightL7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("INVOICE DATE ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL7.Colspan = 5;
                    rightL7.Border = 0;
                    rightL7.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL7.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL7.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    rightL7.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL7);
                    PdfPCell rightL8 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_invdate, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    rightL8.Colspan = 5;
                    rightL8.Border = 0;
                    rightL8.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL8.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL8.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL8.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL8);


                    PdfPCell rightL9 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("INVOICE TOTAL ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    rightL9.Colspan = 5;
                    rightL9.Border = 0;
                    rightL9.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL9.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL9.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL9.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL9);
                    PdfPCell rightL10 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$" + _total, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    rightL10.Colspan = 5;
                    rightL10.Border = 0;
                    rightL10.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    rightL10.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    rightL10.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    rightL10.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    right.AddCell(rightL10);




                    PdfPCell pob5 = new PdfPCell(right);
                    pob5.Colspan = 4;
                    pob5.Border = 0;
                    table.AddCell(pob5);


                    PdfPCell _Middetail = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice Submitted To", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 8)));
                    _Middetail.Colspan = 4;
                    _Middetail.Border = 0;

                    table.AddCell(_Middetail);


                    PdfPCell MidRight = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRight.Colspan = 4;
                    MidRight.Border = 0;
                    table.AddCell(MidRight);



                    PdfPCell MidRight1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRight1.Colspan = 4;
                    MidRight1.Border = 0;
                    table.AddCell(MidRight1);

                    PdfPCell pdfSpace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    pdfSpace.Colspan = 8;
                    pdfSpace.Border = 0;
                    pdfSpace.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    pdfSpace.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    table.AddCell(pdfSpace);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentre = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentre.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighCentre.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentre.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                    MidRighCentre.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    MidRighCentre.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentre.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentre);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order #", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreH.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighCentreH.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreH.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    MidRighCentreH.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    MidRighCentreH.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentreH.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreH);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreService = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Service", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreService.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighCentreService.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreService.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    MidRighCentreService.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    MidRighCentreService.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentreService.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreService);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreDesc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreDesc.Colspan = 4;
                    MidRighCentreDesc.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreDesc.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    MidRighCentreDesc.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    MidRighCentreDesc.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentreDesc.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreDesc);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreTotal = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreTotal.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighCentreTotal.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreTotal.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
                    MidRighCentreTotal.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                    MidRighCentreTotal.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentreTotal.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreTotal);




                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreDesc10 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Billing Group Sub Total  :", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreDesc10.Colspan = 7;
                    MidRighCentreDesc10.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreDesc10.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreDesc10);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreTotal11 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$" + _total, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreTotal11.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighCentreTotal11.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreTotal11.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                    MidRighCentreTotal11.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreTotal11);

                    PdfPCell MidRighCentreInvTotal = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice Total  :", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 10)));
                    MidRighCentreInvTotal.Colspan = 7;
                    MidRighCentreInvTotal.Border = 0;
                    MidRighCentreInvTotal.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighCentreInvTotal);

                    PdfPCell MidRighINVTotal11 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$" + _total, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    MidRighINVTotal11.Colspan = 1;
                    MidRighINVTotal11.Border = 0;
                    MidRighINVTotal11.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    MidRighINVTotal11.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    table.AddCell(MidRighINVTotal11);


                    PdfPCell pdfFooterTempI = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                    pdfFooterTempI.Colspan = 8;
                    pdfFooterTempI.Border = 0;
                    pdfFooterTempI.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    pdfFooterTempI.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    table.AddCell(pdfFooterTempI);

                    PdfPCell pdfFooterTempLast = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" \n \t \t PAYMENT IS DUE ON RECEIPT. LAST PAYMENT WILL BE ASSESSED  \n \t  A LATE FEE. PLEASE INCLUDE INV # WITH PAYMENT. THANK YOU. \n \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t  FOR CHOOSING ABSOLUTE.  ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE, 11)));
                    pdfFooterTempLast.Colspan = 8;
                    pdfFooterTempLast.Border = 0;
                    pdfFooterTempLast.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    pdfFooterTempLast.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
                    //pdfFooterTempLast.HorizontalAlignment ;
                    table.AddCell(pdfFooterTempLast);
                    doc.Add(table);
                    doc.NewPage();
                    doc.Close();

                    //if (TotalCount == arg.Length)
                    //{
                    //    doc.Close();

                    //}



                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    doc.Close();
                }
                // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfFilePath);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks for your comment and advice

Comment: You've posted 414 lines of codes above but most aren't related to your specific problem. For instance, `rightL2.Border = 1;` isn't related to multiple pages and can be removed from the problem. Also, you're adding 26 cells to a table. Unless those are related to the problem those can be removed, too. You should be able to distill your problem down to 25 to 50 lines probably which will make it easier for us to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTextSharp you only have one document and multiple pages.  So remove the doc.Close(); after Newpage(); and put it outside the loop.

```
doc.NewPage();
doc.Close(); // remove this: it will stop any further writing
```

You also only create a new table on the first iteration of the loop.  I'm not sure why.  I'd have thought you'd want a new table for each invoice.

```
table = new PdfPTable(8); // move outside of the if (TotalCount == 1)
```

Also remove the Try / Catch to allow any errors to show though.

```
// this stuff should be outside of the loop too
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
```

Comment: i did this but pdf is not generating

Comment: i did this changes but this is generating two pdf if i pass two invoice no

Comment: Updated again. Basically any document.open / close / PdfWriter create should be outside of the loop.

Comment: is this after the end of my foreach loop

Comment: i upload my zip folder in this link can you please take a look https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5A781525673E5F1%21989

Comment: You should be creating a new document - opening it, then looping over your invoice ids, creating a new table for each, adding the table to the doc. Then closing the document after the loop.